# Draw circle inside a label

Tags: c#

I am trying to draw a circle using Windows Form at runtime inside a label control. I am trying to display green or red circle and display the text('L1' or 'L2') on top of it. Could you please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to SetStyle in the Constructor so you can control the paint

```
  this.SetStyle(
                ControlStyles.UserPaint
                | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint
                | ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor
                , true );
```

Then you are responsible for painting the entire label including the background and the text.  Override OnPaint

```
protected override void OnPaint( PaintEventArgs e ) {
  Graphics g = e.Graphics;
  Brush b = new SolidBrush( this.ForeColor );
  SizeF sf = g.MeasureString( this.Text, this.Font );

  Padding p = Padding.Add( this.Padding, this.Margin );

  // do not forget to include the offset for you circle and text in the x, y position
  float x = p.Left;
  float y = p.Top;

  g.DrawString(  this.Text, this.Font, b, x, y );
}
```

After you have draw the label text, then use g.DrawEllipse to draw the circle you want and where you want.  Then use g.DrawString to position the text above it.

Keep in mind that if you must provide everything bit of the paint that you set properties for so this is only to be used for the labels that conform to the standard you are going to set

Comment: Thank you. What is 'TextAlign'?

Comment: TextAlign is the ContentAlignment of the string.  It tells you the position of the string within the labels confines

Comment: Thanks for your help. I appreciate. I added a label control to the form and override onpaint. I am getting xAlign and TextAlign doesn't exist in current context message. What am I missing here?

Comment: Just ignore that and use the edited version.  I copied it out of my custom Label paint.

Comment: I don't see any circle drawn on the form.

Comment: I am using the following code to draw the circle behind the label. It's not working.
            Brush B = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
    Pen P = new Pen(Color.Black);
             Rectangle Rect = new Rectangle();
             g.DrawEllipse(P, Rect);
             g.FillEllipse(B, Rect);

Comment: the Rect has no width and height values... they are both 0

Comment: Thank you. I added Width and Height to Rect. It looks good. But is there any way I can center the text? It's always displaying on the top of the circle.Here is override paint method.

            Rectangle Rect = new Rectangle(p.Left, p.Top, 25, 25);
            g.DrawEllipse(P, Rect);
            g.FillEllipse(B, Rect);
            g.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, b, x, y);

Answer (score 1):

To do this programmatically you can use the Label's [`CreateGraphics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.creategraphics.aspx) method to get the [`Graphics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx).  You can then use the [`DrawElipse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawellipse.aspx) and the [`DrawString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring.aspx) methods to create the image you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a resource Image, you can set the Image property on the Label, and then set the Text Alignment and the Image Alignment properties to get it to fall where you want.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have a resource image. Is it possible using Graphics object?

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with Nick. Have 4 images with various combination and show it dynamically.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Raja